# Showing Bayesian updating in R

Tags: r, bayesian, function

I'm very new to Bayesian and am very interested in understanding the concept that each **posterior** from a previous test, can be used as a **prior** for a current test or in Lindley's (2000) words *'Yesterday's posterior is today's prior'*.

To see this in action, however, I was wondering if I could explore this concept in `R` as a function for the simple problem of estimating the probability of success from binomially distributed data.

I tried something but my `R` skills were not advanced enough to show this updating concept. Since *Stack Overflow* was not of much help, I am wondering if any of our colleagues here might know the trick?

*(In `R` code below, `pr` = prior; `lk` = likelihood; `ps` = posterior)*

```
update <- function(n, dat){

for(i in 1:length(n)){           
pr = function(x) dbeta(x, 1, 1)
lk = function(x) dbinom(dat[i], n[i], x)  # So, here first `n = 100` and 
ps = function(x) pr(x)*lk(x)              # `dat = 55` will go thru first 
 }                                        # round of the loop and produce
curve(ps)                                 # a `ps`. But in the second run of
}                                         # the loop, the `ps` just
# Example of use:                         # produced will be used as `pr`
update(n = c(100, 50), dat = c(55, 60) )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't updating the "new" prior with the posterior!  And it's much harder to do with functions, unless you're good with R functional programming, than with discretized values for $p$.

I'm constructing an example similar to what you were doing, but not exactly the same.  Here I assume the data follows a Binomial($n=10$, $p=0.5$) distribution,that $n=10$ is known, and that the initial prior on $p$ is uniform.  At each of 20 iterations I generate one new data point from the Binomial(10, 0.5) distribution and update the posterior with it.

Here's some R code that will do the job:

```
# True distribution
p <- 0.5
n <- 10

# Prior on p (n assumed known), discretized
p_values <- seq(0.01,0.99,0.001)
pr <- dbeta(p_values,1,1)
pr <- 1000 * pr / sum(pr)  # Have to normalize given discreteness
plot(pr~p_values, col=1, ylim=c(0, 14), type="l")

# Run for 20 samples
for (i in 1:20) {
   x <- rbinom(1, n, p) 
   ps <- dbinom(x, n, p_values) * pr
   ps <- 1000 * ps / sum(ps)
   lines(ps~p_values, col=(i+1))

   pr = ps
}
```

And here's the graphical result:

[image: Sequence of posterior distributions]

As you can see, the posterior distributions do concentrate rather quickly and, despite a poor initial sample, are shifting their peak closer and closer to the true value of 0.5, albeit with some randomness.

Comment: That's what makes the prior for the next iteration equal to the posterior of the current iteration.

Comment: 'Yesterday's posterior is today's prior'.

Comment: I mean programtically speaking why and how?

Comment: If you don't, then your prior doesn't change from one iteration to the next, and you are always updating your *original* prior with one data point.  That means you forget all the data points you've already seen, you are actually only using the most recent data point you've seen.  That assignment is the mechanism which allows the update mechanism to "remember" the current data point when the next iteration occurs.

Comment: That's partially correct.  In fact, Bayesian statistics is really about small samples, where "small" isn't well-defined, because as your sample size gets "large", the estimates concentrate around the real value so closely that prior information doesn't make a difference any more.  But note that at the first iteration we don't really have any prior information; the uniform distribution on $p$ basically says "I think all values are equally likely", so you don't benefit except for the fact that having a prior allows you to be Bayesian.

Comment: $n$ as in the parameter of the Binomial distribution; I've updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Yes, I'm just making the assumption that the only parameter you're trying to estimate in the example problem is $p$ to keep things simple.  This is a pretty common assumption, but doesn't actually need to be made.

Comment: Right thanks, I remember in some book I had read that in wildlife sciences $n$ is a commonly estimated parameter.